# Multiplying a normal distribution by a log-normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, approximation

I need direction to approximate the resultant probability distribution of the product of two independent distributions: $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $lognormal(\mu_{N}, \sigma_{N}^2)$, where

$\mu_{N}$ is the normal mean and $\mu_{N} = 0$, and

$\sigma_{N}$ is the normal SD

Is the resultant distribution a log-normal distribution? If yes, what are the normal mean and normal SD? If no, is there a way to approximate the pdf for dummies? I am an R user.

Comment: Are the two variables independent?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, they are.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution#Derivation_for_independent_random_variables) method for calculating the PDF of the product of two independent continuous random variables, in terms of their PDFs. But no such calculation is needed to note that, since a Normally distributed $X$ can be positive or negative but a log-normally distributed $Y$ is non-negative, $XY$ can be positive or negative and hence isn't log-normal. As for the mean and variance, note that $$\Bbb EXY=\Bbb EX\Bbb EY=\mu\exp\left(\mu_N+\frac12\sigma_N^2\right),\,\\\operatorname{Var}XY=\Bbb EX^2\Bbb EY^2-(\Bbb EXY)^2\\=(\mu^2+\sigma^2)\exp\left(2\mu_N+2\sigma_N^2\right)-\mu^2\exp\left(2\mu_N+\sigma_N^2\right).$$